# Cannot access the internet after disconnecting AnyConnect VPN

Tags: network, wifi, vpn

Using Cisco AnyConnect to connect to my company VPN from my personal computer.
No problem installing and running the app but if I disconnect AnyConnect (icon in the menu bar > Disconnect), then I can't access the internet anymore. Note that I cannot *quit* the application, I can only *disconnect* it. If I uninstall AnyConnect completely then I can access the internet again.
I compared my wifi network settings (Wi-fi, TCP/IP, DNS, etc. tabs) before and after the installation and they are the same.

I assume AnyConnect must have change the network settings somewhere else though. Any idea where I should start looking?

AnyConnect version: **4.10.03104**

OS version: **11.5.2**

Comment: I am having this problem as well on MacOS 12.1 One thing I notice is that in System Preferences, Network the adaptor still shows as connected after disconnecting in AnyConnect, and quitting the app.

Comment: I've run into similar issues, but the internet connection just dies in the middle of being used. It seems to be the network filters it installs – if they're deleted, the network is restored.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with the AnyConnect profile file in */opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/*. I played a bit with the attributes there (*AutomaticVPNPolicy*, *AlwaysOn*) and was able to quit AnyConnect and access the internet.

(Still looking for a better way to switch between VPN and no-VPN modes)